# How can I export a SQLAlchemy schema for Breeze?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, breeze

I have implemented a collection of APIs using Flask + SQLAlchemy backend.  I want to use BreezeJS in the frontend.  How can I export my db schema which can be understood by Breeze JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Davidism is correct on both counts.

Breeze needs metadata for the JSON at the server boundary. That may map directly to your db schema but it doesn't have to.

You can define the metadata entirely in code and that may be easier than trying to generate it from your db schema. It's really not hard to write metadata by hand.

It's up to you to decide how much of the breeze query URI (OData query) you want to support server side. You don't have to support the query at all. Plenty of folks find plenty of value in breeze w/o querying simply from how it helps manage data on the client.